# Analytics Engine: double ON for app

Tags: ios, ios7, analytics

I'm watching the console of my iPad 2 (iOS 7), and I stumbled upon this line after a crash of my app :

> networkd[76] < Warning >: Analytics Engine: double ON for app: dns.reversed.my

I've found no info online about this "Analytics Engine" ; what is this? Is this Apple's own engine?

And should I worry about this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`networkd[76]` means it's a log message from Apple's system network daemon. Nothing to do with your program, don't worry about it.

Comment: Alright! And about this analytics engine, do you know what it does?

Comment: Nope. I imagine it is part of the new performance features of iOS7 and Mavericks, though it could just be a more boring analytics gatherer.